# I can't add links to any of my menu

Tags: routes

I can't add links to any of my menus.

I go to the menu, click on **add link**, and fill all the required data; I get the message, "Your configuration has been saved." It doesn't seem it is what it is done.

[image: screenshot]

All modules and core are updated to the last versions.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache just in case?

Comment: Fixed. Problem was that path contained a 20% instead of the `space`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that the path contained "20%" instead of a space.

Comment: can you please describe the path contained "20%" instead of space, as i have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I encountered something similar, but in my case I hadn't noticed that **I had unchecked the 'published' checkbox,** so eventually ended up with about a dozen duplicate links after retrying!

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to be able to provide a menu link to unpublished content there's a module for that - http://drupal.org/project/menu_view_unpublished