# Can't add menu items to new menu

Tags: routes

I get a message: your configuration has been saved, but when I look at list links it says no links have been added.

I found a similar question and tried the answers to no luck.

I added a new menu Login Menu which worked fine and shows up with the other default menus.
I created a page content to serve as my login page for the site. When I try to add a link to my new Login Menu it says it has been saved, but it does not show up.

My objective is to move the User login block to show only on it's own page. So I need a menu for anonymous users to go to for logging in.

Comment: Is the page you are trying to add to the menu published?

Comment: Yes, I can navigate to the page via the url, and I have verified it is published.

Comment: Similar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/i-cant-add-links-to-any-of-my-menu

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the hierarchical menu module 7.x-3.0-alpha5. Although no error is created when trying to add a new item to a menu, an error is generated when adding new content with a menu link. This error allowed me to search for a solution.

I disabled the module and was able to add a new menu item to my new menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the menu cache: [menu_rebuild](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7)().

In Drupal 7 go to: Administration -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance and click "Clear All Caches"
(example.com/admin/config/development/performance if clean URLs are enabled)